# What constitutes the region which Lo Yilbash is based on

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, clothing, shiurim-measurements, lo-yilbash

According to Halacha, Lo Yilbash (the prohibition of cross dressing as the opposite gender), is based on what is customarily considered men’s clothing/women’s clothing in a region (**מנהג המדינה**).

My question is, what is the Shiur (size) of the region that determines this? Is it countries, cities, or something else?

For example in Scotland men wear kilts which are like skirts and would generally be considered women’s clothing in the rest of the UK, do Scots follow the region of Scotland or the majority of the UK as a whole?

Similarly some things which are considered men’s clothing in America may be women’s clothing in another city or state.

What exactly is the size of the geographic region we determine this off of?

Comment: The answer to this question is הַכּל כְּמִנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה. This is a term used throughout halachic writing and has a specific meaning. If you'd like to know what it means, may I recommend untying this question from Lo Yilbash, and just asking what הַכּל כְּמִנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mishneh Torah Hilchot Avodah Zara, upon which the Shulchan Aruch on this seems to be based](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.182.5?lang=bi&with=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Foreign%20Worship%20and%20Customs%20of%20the%20Nations&lang2=he), states הַכּל כְּמִנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה - everything goes after the local custom.

It's a term that is very clear and understood (so much so you'll struggle to find any source actually defining it because it is so obvious). You can't pinpoint it to a "geographic size" as seems to be presumed in the question; it can be any size, and therefore even the smallest size can be relevant. If you find one town in Scotland where men never wear kilts and would be considered "dressing like a woman" for doing so, then that would be the מנהג המדינה, even if the wider region all wears kilts.

That's what הַכּל כְּמִנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה means - whatever applies to you where you are.

E.g. if a man's **locals** would consider him to be dressing like a woman if he wore a specific garment or adornment (and the converse), then it would fall under Lo Yilbash. I say "fall under" because even then, it might still be ok, depending on other factors [such what the purpose of wearing it is and what else one is wearing](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.182.7.1?lang=bi) - this mitzva is quite complex, and interesting, with a lot of striking opinions.

Either way, always CYLOR about practical questions.

Comment: Yes, I’m sure OP knows this. But what determines the size of the medina in regards to the minhag hamedina? A city?

Comment: With all due respect you didn’t answer the core of my question (what is the definition of locale) at all

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear. This phrasing is invoked a lot in Chazal, and it generally means whatever applies to you where you are at the time, regardless of how large or small a region that applies to. I'll think of a way of improving the answer, thanks for the feedback so far

Comment: Marit ayn applies even if you're alone

Comment: So, can I wear women's clothes in my home, because that's the minhag in my home?

Comment: @Loani you cannot have a "minhag" in just your own home, what makes that a minhag? By definition it needs to be a substantial quantity of people living in some sort of medina, doing the same thing as part of their custom or law, for it to be a full blown minhag.

Comment: @RabbiKaii then you haven't answered the question... How big is the area needed? How local is 'local'? What's a substantial quantity of people?

Comment: Also, I can be the only one in the 'Medina' to go according to a certain minhag nowadays, like if a sefardi moves in to an Ashkenazi neighborhood... So according to that, could a Scotsman wear a kilt in England?

Comment: @Loani The answer to the question asked is הַכּל כְּמִנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה, and your questions are about minhag, and lo yilbash in general

Comment: The question is 'what is the shiur of lo yilbash?' you answered הכל כמנהגו המדינה. I'm pointing out that that doesn't answer the question, because it doesn't define the shiur, it just gives it a name. In fact, you say in your answer that "...even the smallest size can be relevant" which is why I asked about a minhag in my own home.

Comment: @Loani I understand your points but these are fringe cases you are asking about that I think would be best asked in their own questions.

Comment: Isn't that the point of shiur, though? To get the minimum size that still 'counts', even if it's a fringe case?