What is considered a "makom" in "Minhag Hamakom"?
When we talk about Minhag Hamakom (place), what locality are we talking about: a country, a city, a neighborhood, or a family home?

Helpful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/139004/31534

Traditionally, it is about personal association or subordination with a local rabbi or a Jewish court. So the "makom" can be anything from a shared building to a country. If two or more courts coexist in the same place (e.g. different Hassidic sects in Meah Shearim) each one is considered Minhag Hamakom. Some 150 years ago, when Ashkenazi Hassids were coming to Israel, traditionally ruled by Sefardic rabbis, they quickly established their own institutions so they would not be obligated to comply with MH.

It's not entirely clear from the question which type on minhag hamakom he is referring to. This answer discusses the minhag hamakom of makom shenahagu of Pesachim 50 - the obligation to adopt the customs of the place one lives. I don't think minhag hamakom often mentioned as a deciding factor in Choshen Mishpat is the same.

The implications of the responsa of R' Moshe Feinstein zt"l (Igros Moshe OC 1:158, EH 1:59) is that 'minhag hamakom' applies even within one home.
R' Moshe discusses the concept of a married woman adopting the customs of her husband, and he categorizes this within the framework of minhag hamakom. [See the teshuva for a very original insight by R' Moshe zt"l that even according to the Rambam (Yom Tov 8:20) that one is obligated by the customs of the his original place, a wife entering the domain of her husband is different.]
A similar analogy is mentioned by Minchas Yitzchok (4:83), (albeit with a slightly different application).
